# URI Scheme for https when login is email

Tags: http, https, uri

I'm doing a https authentication with login and password, according to RFC the URI should look like this:

```
https://username:password@example.com:8042/
```

But when the login is an email, the `@` sign is interpreted as the host delimiter:

```
https://username@example.com:password@example.com:8042/
```

How should a correct URI look like?

[edit] Some background: I'm retriving PivotalTracker authentication token using

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'open-uri'

def validate_with_credentials
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(authentication_uri, :http_basic_authentication => [email, password]))
end

def authentication_uri
  URI('https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v4/me')
end
```

This works, but I want to stub the url in my feature tests, I'm using FakeWeb gem:

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, 'https://correct_email@example.com:correct_password@www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v4/me',
    :body => File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'pivotal_tracker', 'responses', 'authorization_success.xml')),
    :status => ['200', 'OK'])
```

The problem here is that the uri shouldn't have double `@`, I get exception:

> URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme https does not accept registry part:
>   correct_email@example.com:correct_password@www.pivotaltracker.com (or
>   bad hostname?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use encoding and replace `@` with `%40`. Courtesy of [ravi parekh](https://superuser.com/a/532530/128382)